# Why is this button click Angular Unit test not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a unit test where I want to test if a function is called on a button click. But I keep getting this error: `Expected spy archive to have been called.`, and I can't figure out why it is not working.

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong? For context see the code below.

**This is my test**

```js
it('should call archive function on button click', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'archive');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.project = rh.getProjects(1)[0];
    dh.clickButton('Archive');

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.archive).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

**This is the dh aka DOMHelper**

```js
clickButton(buttonText: string) {
    this.findAll('button').forEach(button => {
      const buttonElement: HTMLButtonElement = button.nativeElement;
      if (buttonElement.textContent === buttonText) {
        buttonElement.click();
      }
    });
}

findAll(tagName: string) {
    return this.fixture.debugElement
      .queryAll(By.css(tagName));
}
```

**This is the html**

```html
<td data-label="Title">{{ project.title }}</td>
<td data-label="Owner">{{ getOwnerName(project.owner) }}</td>
<td data-label="Actions">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="dashboard">Dashboard</button>
    <button *ngIf="authService.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser.uid == project.owner" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="archive">Archive</button>
</td>
```

**This is the component.ts file**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from 'src/app/models/project';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { ProjectService } from 'src/app/services/project.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'tr[app-joined-project-item]',
    templateUrl: './joined-project-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./joined-project-item.component.css'],
})
export class JoinedProjectItemComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() public project: Project;

    constructor(public authService: AuthService, public projectService: ProjectService, private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    archive() {
        this.projectService.updateArchivedStatusProject(this.project);
    }

    dashboard() {
        this.router.navigate(['/projects/' + this.project.id + '/dashboard'])
    }

    getOwnerName(userId: string) {
        return Object.values(this.project.members).find((member: any) => member['userId'] === userId)['name'];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

When I test it where I check if the service function get called, I get the following error: `Expected spy updateArchivedStatusProject to have been called with: *Project Object* but it was never called.`

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule],
            declarations: [JoinedProjectItemComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: ProjectService, useClass: MockProjectService },
                { provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService },
                { provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));

it('should call archive function on button click', async(() => {
    spy = spyOn(TestBed.get(ProjectService), 'updateArchivedStatusProject');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.project = rh.getProjects(1)[0];
    dh.clickButton('Archive');

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(rh.projects[0]);
}));
```

Comment: I would **not** recommend testing the component by spying on its methods. Use a test double of the service, and assert that its `updateArchivedStatusProject` method gets called with the right project. In general you should test *behaviour*, not implementation, via the public interface (for an Angular component: `@Input`/`@Output`s, the DOM, and interactions with injected collaborators).

Comment: I added an update to the question. When I test if the mocked service function get called, I get the error that it was never called

Comment: Your `clickButton` method in the `DOMHelper` does not throw an error if the button you are trying to click is not in the DOM. As there is an `*ngIf` on it I'm guessing that it's not. Try to log the found buttons and / or throw an error if the array returned from `findAll` is empty. That would help with debugging failing tests.

Comment: The button gets found in that method, because if I log inside the `if (buttonElement.textContent === buttonText)` I get the button `<button _ngcontent-a-c36="" class="btn btn-primary">Archive</button>`

Comment: I think the problem is different here (see answer). But I think throwing an error in that method in case of missing elements will help you in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the brackets in the click handler. Should be :

```
<button (...) (click)="archive()">Archive</button>
```

**EDIT:**

The fact that you assumed it's the test fault and not an actual simple bug shows that you do not trust your tests. That may happen when they fail a lot while the application works correctly. It suggests that there might be something wrong with how you write test.

One suggestion I would give is to make the tools you use in tests as explicit as possible. For example the `clickButton` could be rewritten to something like:

```
clickButton(buttonText: string) {
    const foundButtons = this.findAll('button')
      .map(button => button.nativeElement)
      .filter(button => button.innerText === buttonText);

    if (foundButtons.length !== 1) {
      fail(`Expected exactly one button with text "${buttonText}" but found ${foundButtons.length}`);
    }

    foundButtons[0].click();
}
```